# Microsoft Word: Digital Signature in document has "recoverable signature" error

Tags: microsoft-word, security, certificate, digital-signature

I am trying to add a digital signature to a document in Microsoft Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2110). When signing, Word says:

> The certificate you selected cannot be verified. Please check your network connection.

I am able to sign the document anyway, but "**Recoverable Signature**" is shown in the signature field. The details say (again):

> The signer's certificate can't be verified, please try again later or check your network connection.

Research showed that the issue seems to be quite common. In most cases, a certificate in the chain is not trusted. For me, the certificate (chain) is shown as valid.

My certificate chain consists of a root CA and the certificate that I am using to sign the document. Both certificates are self-created / self-signed; the root CA is installed as one of the *trusted root certification authorities* and I can see that the chain is trusted as expected.
This implies that both certificates are valid (not expired, not revoked).
My internet connection is working and the system clock is correct.

No CRL is involved. However, to make sure that Word does not expect one, I've tried a similar setup with an intermediate CA which specifies a CRL distribution point. I could verify that word requests the specified CRL (CRL without revocations). The result was the same as in the simplified scenario described above.

**Questions**:

- Why is an internet connection actually required in this scenario? What does Word actually check (online)?
- What is causing the "recoverable signature" error? How to make a self-signed certificate 100% accepted without warnings?

---

**Update:**
After copying my (John Doe) certificate from *Personal* to *Trusted People*, the error disappears. This arises two new questions:
Why does Word not trust my *Personal* certificates and, more importantly, **why to I have to trust individual certificates (people) when I already trust the certificates issuer (CA)**? I think that this contradicts the principle of the chain of trust.
I'd like to avoid having to trust individual certificates, which is why I have the CA.

---

**Screenshot and certificate details:**

[image: Digital Signature and certificate details]

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: [removed]
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = DE, O = [removed], CN = [removed] Root CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 24 12:49:00 2021 GMT
            Not After : Dec 24 12:49:00 2022 GMT
        Subject: CN = John Doe, emailAddress = john.doe@example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            [removed]
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                [removed]
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
            Netscape Cert Type: 
                SSL Client, S/MIME
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         [removed]
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[removed]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Are both certificates in your certificate store? "Why is an internet connection actually required in this scenario?" - The error message is an "either-or" message, the certificate could not be validated, because the certificate used to sign the document is not in the certificate store or least according to [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/312d7bd9-10c2-4ede-97e0-a17e50458b7f/trouble-trusting-users-identity-in-a-recoverable-signature) that's the case.  Although, knowing what I know about certificates (a good deal) that was my exact thought

Comment: thanks, I've updated my question. Why is my trust in the CA ignored by Word?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how was your certificate created? I see it lacks Extended Key Usage (which is technically optional but I wouldn't be entirely surprised if some software required it) yet has Netscape Cert Type (which has been obsolete for maybe 15 years)... Is the certificate issued directly by the root CA or are there intermediate CAs? What extensions do all those CAs have?

Comment: @Ramhound: They are not. OP contradicts themselves and states that the document certificate is self-signed _and_ issued by a CA at the same time (a certificate issued by a CA is by definition not self-signed) – and the shown certificate has an "Issuer" that is different from "Subject", which indeed means that it is _not_ self-signed, because it has an issuer that is not itself. Either way, that is not what I asked about.

Comment: Certs were generated with xca; those netscape extensions are included by default. Only the CA is self-signed; the *John Doe* certificate is signed by the CA.

Answer (score 1):

I could figure out what happens and got it working now.
Conclusion: **Word does not accept certificates that cannot be revoked** because no CRL distribution point is specified in a certificate.

The error message *"Check your network connection"* can be misleading if no CRL distribution point is specified because you would not expect that something needs to be checked then.

Once I specify a CRL it finally works.
The *Root CA* is installed as trusted root certificate and all derived certificates are validated without errors.

My pitfall was: CRL distribution points must be specified in the *issued* certificates, not in the issuer's certificate. In the described scenario

- the *Root CA* does not specify any CRL distribution point (like probably most Root CA's).
- The end instance certificate *John Doe* specifies a CRL distribution point where the *Root CA* publishes its CRL.

If an intermediate CA is used, two CRL's must be maintained and specified: One for the certificates (CAs) issued by the *Root CA* and another for certificates issued by the *intermediate CA* .